# How to escape @ sign inside JSDoc comments in NetBeans

Tags: javascript, netbeans, jsdoc

I have a simple method in API, that allows searching objects with JSONPath. As its syntax is pretty much unfamiliar to junior developers, i decided to provide some examples within JSDoc comment. Yet, here is the catch, - `@` sign is treated as a start of new jsdoc-tag, and so description becomes corrupted.

Question: **how to make NetBeans** (or jsdoc in general) **ignore `@` signs inside of particular code chunk ?** Preferably, within `@example` block.

So this code, would show unmodified within tooltip:

`$..book[?(@.price<10)]   // - filter all books cheaper than 10`

Also, `@example`, `<code>`, `<pre>` - do not help.

Html entity `&#64;` is converted to `@` in tooltip, *but* it looks unreadable in the code itself (`$..book[?(&#64;.price<10)]`) *and* its only working in main jsdoc text ...

Comment: [@ignore](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/TagIgnore) may work.

Answer (score 7):

This is a pretty old question, but I was having the same problem, except in VSCode and thought I'd share a possible solution.

What finally worked was moving `@returns` *below* the example and, unfortunately, not using `@example`, e.g.:

````
/**
 * some description
 * 
 * For example:
 * ```js
 * $..book[?(@.price<10)] // - filter all books cheaper than 10
 * ```
 * @returns {*} whatever you're returning
 */
````

This is not ideal, but works for VSCode's tooltip; I'm not sure if it'll work with NetBeans.

Comment: If you download Netbeans and check that it works - i will gladly accept the answer  p.s.: i don't have Netbeans on my machines anymore, so cannot verify it myself.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this will work for all environments, but when using VSCode on a typescript (.ts) file I was able to use template strings to achieve nicely displayed example code

````
/**
 * @description
 * This function totally does something.
 *
 * @example```
import { SomeThing } from '@mycompany/my-cool-library';

DoSomething(SomeThing)```
 * 
 * @returns string
 */
````

Makes the tooltip display like:

[image: escaping_the_@_sign]

Comment: This also doesn't work for me but making the string a template string did, so using ` instead of ' around the string with @ in it