# jsdoc @ character inside code block

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, documentation, jsdoc

I'm trying to write documentation for a Module function like this:

````
/**
 * Usage:
 *
 * ```
 * @NgModule({
 *      imports: [
 *          BrowserModule,
 *          ...,
 *          ThisModule.forRoot({
 *              name: 'Name',
 *              version: '1.0',
 *      ],
 * }),
 * ```
 * 
 * @param config Service configuration parameters
 */
public static forRoot(config: SVConfig) {
````

The problem is with `@NgModule`. I've tried with:

````
* ```
* &#064;NgModule
````

Seems that html entitites works well outside code (```), but not inside code block (it does something weird like making `NgModule` in bold and new line)

Also tried `\@`, `{@literal @}`, `\u0064`, `@@` with no success.
The most friendly I've found is `(@)NgModule`.

Any suggestion please?

Comment: This was [asked 5 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223916/how-to-escape-sign-inside-jsdoc-comments-in-netbeans) with no answer and is also an outstanding issue in [compodoc](https://github.com/compodoc/compodoc/issues/304)

Answer (score 13):

I've had luck using an alternate @ symbol in the unicode space: [U+FF20 (＠)](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+FF20). It makes the documentation look correct, but unfortunately won't work if someone copy/pastes the code block. This appears to be an open issue since at least 2012 so I'm not holding my breath for a better fix.

Comment: The only solution work, should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 7):

Sadly, special symbols are not supported in jsDoc inside `@example` block. They work only inside inline code blocks, like this one:

````
```js
&#64;Module
```
````

This will result in the proper `@Module` output.

And unlike `@example`, you cannot place an inline code block after everything, because it is inline, which means it will be somewhere before your `@returns` section. Awkward, I know.

The same goes when you want to use something like multi-line comment in your code example, etc.

````
```js
a.setParams(&#47;* parameters here *&#47;);
```
````

outputs: `a.setParams(/* parameters here */);`

Answer (score 2):

The closest one I came up is to use [Invisible Separater](https://unicode-explorer.com/c/2063) just before `@` symbol.

e.g.:

````js
/**
 * Usage:
 *
 * ```
 * ⁣@NgModule({
 *      imports: [
 *          BrowserModule,
 *          ...,
 *          ThisModule.forRoot({
 *              name: 'Name',
 *              version: '1.0',
 *      ],
 * }),
 * ```
 * 
 * @param config Service configuration parameters
 */
public static forRoot(config: SVConfig) {
````

It would look like this in VSCode:

[image: Screenshot from VSCode]

### Warning:

If someone copy+paste the comment displayed on VSCode, the code will not work since it will also copy this invisible character. VSCode wil probably complain that there is an invalid character.