# VS Code with @ sign in JSDoc example

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I just cann't make @ sign works inside a code block in @example JSDoc attribute, this always break the visualization:
Original:

````
   * @example
   * ```js
   * import { BadRequestError } from '@nexsolab/common-network';
   * 
   * const error = new BadRequestError()
   *   .addInvalidParam('token', 'Token should be informed')
   *   .mount();
   * ```
````

VS Code rendered tip:

```
@example

import { BadRequestError } from '  

*@nexsolab*  
/common-network';

const error = new BadRequestError()
.addInvalidParam('token', 'Token should be informed')
.mount();
```

Also
`import { BadRequestError } from '&#64;nexsolab/common-network';`
`* import { BadRequestError } from '&commat;nexsolab/common-network';`
doesn't works.

I forgot something or this is a VS Code bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a limitation of JSDoc as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49393923/jsdoc-character-inside-code-block). As a workaround you could probably use the unicode @ U+FF20. So in your example string substitute the @ symbol with \uFF20